# upgrade from 15.04 problems

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade, updates, 15.04

I know there are similar questions, but the reasons are always different, so...I am trying to upgrade my system just the usual way, that is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And I am getting a notification that

> An upgrade from vivid to xenial is not supported with this tool.

What could be done?

Comment: Since 15.04 is no longer supported, neither are the tools to upgrade to a supported version. At this point, you might as well backup everything and install 16.04 or 16.10.